# Как заставить EditText заполнить всё свободное пространство в строке?

Tags: android, layout, edittext

Всем доброго времени суток. Хочу чтобы editText заполняло всё свободное пространство в строке. Не знаю как это правильно реализовать. Подскажите кто-нибудь как это сделать[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если у вас проблемы с разметкой - разметку нужно добавить в вопрос, здесь не гадают по картинкам. метка android-studio ставится к вопросам, которые связаны с проблемами в самой IDE, а не с тем, что с ее помощью вы делаете

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте выставить ему ширину `match_parent`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/main"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите чтобы кнопка была под EditText

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText 
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Отправить"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Если хотите чтобы кнопка была была вместе с EditText

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Отправить"/>

</LinearLayout>
```